# How to sort a LinkedList alphabetically?

Tags: sorting, linked-list, alphabetical

I have looked around but none of my research answers how to actually do it or why mine is not working.

```
private LinkedList<Event> events = new LinkedList<Event>();
private LinkedList<Event> tempEvents = new LinkedList<Event>();

public Events()
{
    setup();
}

private void setup()
{   
    events.add(new Event("Breakfast", 10));
    events.add(new Event("Lunch", 15));
    events.add(new Event("Nibbles", 20));
    events.add(new Event("Tea", 25));
    events.add(new Event("Dinner", 30)); 
    events.add(new Event("Snack", 35));
    events.add(new Event("Afters", 40));
}

public Event fromAlpha()
{   
    tempEvents.clear();
    tempEvents = Collections.sort(events, new Comparator<String>());
    return null; 
}
```

Comment: You need to provide a `Comparator<Event>` to sort a `List<Event>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you use Java.

Also I assume that `Event` is your own class that has `getName` and `getNum` methods, like this one

```
class Event {

    private final String name;
    private final int num;

    public Event(String name, int num) {
        this.name = name;
        this.num = num;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getNum() {
        return num;
    }

}
```

So you can sort your `List` with anonymous `Comparator<Event>` class.
You can't sort it with `new Comparator<String>` because you sort `Event`s, not `Strings`s. Also `Collections.sort` method does not return anything, so I have sorted `events` collection.
So here is working example:

```
class Events {

    private LinkedList<Event> events = new LinkedList<Event>();
    private LinkedList<Event> tempEvents = new LinkedList<Event>();

    public Events() {
        setup();
    }

    private void setup() {   
        events.add(new Event("Breakfast", 10));
        events.add(new Event("Lunch", 15));
        events.add(new Event("Nibbles", 20));
        events.add(new Event("Tea", 25));
        events.add(new Event("Dinner", 30)); 
        events.add(new Event("Snack", 35));
        events.add(new Event("Afters", 40));
    }

    public void fromAlpha() {   
        for(Event e : events) {
            System.out.print("{ " + e.getName() + ", " + e.getNum() + " }");
        }
        System.out.println();
        Collections.sort(events, new Comparator<Event>() {
            public int  compare(Event e1, Event e2) {
                return e1.getName().compareTo(e2.getName());
            }
        });
        for(Event e : events) {
            System.out.print("{ " + e.getName() + ", " + e.getNum() + " }");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Here is the result:

```
{ Breakfast, 10 }{ Lunch, 15 }{ Nibbles, 20 }{ Tea, 25 }{ Dinner, 30 }{ Snack, 35 }{ Afters, 40 }
{ Afters, 40 }{ Breakfast, 10 }{ Dinner, 30 }{ Lunch, 15 }{ Nibbles, 20 }{ Snack, 35 }{ Tea, 25 }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
using System.Linq;
...
var sorted = from event in events orderby event.Name descending select event;
```